# Why does $$var['namedIndex'] = 'test' doesnt work?

Tags: php

In PHP you can you

```
$var = 'title';
$$var = 'my new title';
```

and it works fine. But when you try to use it with array, it doesnt work and no errors are reported.

```
$var = 'title';
$$var['en'] = 'my english title';

$var = 'description';
$$var['en'] = 'my english description';
```

Thanks for the help

[EDIT]
If I do

```
$$var = array();
array_push($$var,'test');
```

it works and it outputs

```
title[0] = 'test';
```

But I really need named index : /

Answer (score 4, accepted):

write it like this:

```
${$var}['en']
```

from the docs:

> In order to use variable variables
>   with arrays, you have to resolve an
>   ambiguity problem. That is, if you
>   write $$a[1](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) then the parser needs to
>   know if you meant to use $a[1](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) as a
>   variable, or if you wanted $$a as the
>   variable and then the [1](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) index from
>   that variable. The syntax for
>   resolving this ambiguity is: ${$a[1](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)}
>   for the first case and ${$a}[1](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) for
>   the second.

[Link For Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)

Comment: wow... thanks! I checked the manual but I never found this page. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

What you really want is:

```
${$var}['en']
```

The problem, as stated in the manual, is ambiguity.  When you write `$$var['en']`, it tries to find the value of `$var['en']` first and then find a variable with the name of the value of that index.  The braces in `${$var}['en']` show that you want `$var` to be expanded first.